# How to create a logic app which creates a tab-delimited table?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Right now, I run a stored procedure whose output feeds a "Create CSV Table" Data Operations component.  This component, not surprisingly, outputs a comma-delimited list of fields, which is not supported by our remote system.  The fields need to be tab-delimited.  One would think that the Data Operations component would have a tab (or other character-delimited option).  But no, only commas are available, and no other Data Operations component outputs a tab-delimited table.

Using any mechanism for which we'd have to write code is completely the last option, as there's no need for code to use CSV.  Also, any mechanism which requires paying for 3rd party components is categorically out, as is using any solution which is in preview mode.

The only option we've thought of is to revamp the stored procedure which outputs a single "column" containing the tab-delimited columns, and then output to a file - ostensibly, a comma-delimited file, but one without commas embedded inside (which is allowed for my system) so that the single column isn't itself enquoted.

Otherwise, I guess Function Apps is the solution.  Anyone with ideas?

Comment: Could solve it with my way? Or did you still have some other problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use string function and replace comma with other delimiter. If you could accept this way, after creating the csv table I initiate a string variable with this input `replace(body('Create_CSV_table_2'),',',' ')`.

And this is the result.

[image]

And if you don't want this way, yes you have to solve it with code and the Function is a choice.